# A probability question about distributing n chocolates to k children

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> (a) n identical chocolates are to be distributed among the k students in Tinku’s class.
> Find the probability that Tinku gets at least one chocolate, assuming that the n chocolates
> are handed out one by one in n independent steps. At each step, one chocolate is given to
> a randomly chosen student, with each student having equal chance to receive it.

P(Tinku gets at least one chocolate) = 1 – P(Tinku gets none)$ = 1 − (\frac{k-1}{k})^n.$

> b) Solve the same problem assuming instead that all distributions are equally likely. You
> are given that the number of such distributions is $n+k-1 \choose k-1$.(Here all chocolates are considered interchangeable but students are considered different.)

Part (b) is where I'm confused. I don't understand the question. Can someone please explain what exactly is different from part (a)?

Answer (score 0):

Part (b) is asking you to assume that all the non-negative integer solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+\dots +x_k = n \tag{*}$$
are equally likely.  There are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ such solutions. Given the assumption that all solutions are equally likely, then the probability that $x_1 > 0$ is the number of solutions to $(*)$ where $x_1 >0$, divided by the number of solutions without that constraint.  So to solve the problem, you need to count the number of solutions with $x_1 >0$.

The assumption of part (a), that each piece of chocolate is equally likely to go to any one of the students, is much more realistic than the assumption of part (b).  It's hard to imagine a situation where the second assumption would hold.

Comment: I'm confused, what are $x_1, x_2,.. x_k$?

Comment: Are we saying that child 1 gets $x_1$ chocolates?

Comment: @Tapi Yes, child $i$ gets $x_i$ chocolates, for $i=1,2,3,\dots ,k$.

Comment: Okay. What exactly leads us to consider the question this way? Like in the first case, we're looking at it from the perspective of the chocolates: each chocolate has $k$ choices (children) it could go to, hence the sample space is $k^n$.

Comment: @Tapi In my opinion, part (b) is a totally unrealistic exercise cooked up to give the student some practice in working with integer solutions to equations such as $(*)$.  There are many interesting problems associated with such equations, but I don't think this exercise is one of them, due to its artificiality.

Comment: @Tapi Having thought about this problem some more, I think the point of the exercise is simply to demonstrate that the two approaches (a) and (b) give different answers.  But it should be stressed that (a) is based on reasonable assumptions and (b) is not, so if you see a similar problem about distributions you generally want to adopt the method of (a), not (b).